# Unable to make dynamic, variable-based jsf <h:graphicImage/>

Tags: image, jsf, dynamic

I'm trying to make a template-based application where an image changes, depending on the rest of the content.

I'm using the following code on a jsf-page:

```
<c:set var="identifier" value="#{myBean.currentImage}" />
        <h:graphicImage value="#{resource[identifier]}" alt="pic"/>
```

And the following code:

```
public String getCurrentImage() {
    currentImage = "image_" + currentLessonNumber + "_" + problemIndex;
    return currentImage;
}
```

In a managed Bean, to generate the correct image-source.
I cannot, however, make it work.
Anyone have some insight as to what I am doing wrong?
Much appreciated.

Comment: what is the behaviour you **do** notice?

Comment: Did you try `<h:graphicImage value="#{myBean.currentImage}"/>`? Images are implicit searched in resources.